# How can I insert multiple time a many-to-many relation with flask-sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, many-to-many

I am using flask-sqlalchemy in order to create a RestAPI. The idea is to store playlists with one or several medias inside it. To link these two, I am using a many-to-many relationship.

Sometimes, a same media will be inserted twice inside a playlist but it fails because the relationship table already has the entry.

```
class Media(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'media'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

medias = db.Table('media_playlist',
                  db.Column('media_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('media.id'), primary_key=True),
                  db.Column('playlist_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('playlist.id'), primary_key=True),
                  )

class Playlist(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'playlist'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    medias = db.relationship('Media',
                             secondary=medias,
                             lazy='subquery',
                             backref=db.backref('playlists', lazy=True))
```

The linked error :

```
UNIQUE constraint failed: media_playlist.media_id, media_playlist.playlist_id
```

How would you do to store several times the same link ?

Thank you,
Rom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you setting `primary_key=True` for foreign key columns? [SQLAlchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-many)
Since you are making a column foreign key it means it is going to store multiple times the same value, but when you make it primary key it means it needs to be `unique` and now you have this error `fails UNIQUE constraint`. If you want it to be indexed, you do not have to do anything as DB is indexing foreign keys by default.

Comment: Thank you, I thought the primary key was mandatory to make the system work but it seems to be completely unnecessary since foreign key are indexed